# Angular 2+: change detection, the state between property-change and view-update

Tags: javascript, angular

--------------  update ---------------

ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() run the change detectors for the component and its children. Thus, it might one solution.

-------------- original question ----------------

1. Purpose: I want to get informed after a specific dom element is updated in a component.

   See the picture underneath:
   (change the **text** property will change the content of **p**, which in turn change the height of **p** element in dom)
   [image]
2. Result: 
   the clientHeight of **p** is still the previous value, not the newest one.

   **Expected result**: the newest value
3. possible solutions:

   - I know **ngAfterViewChecked** will get fired every time in the change detection and it stands for the state after the view is updated.
   - Some walkaround solution for this problem can be force the change detection happens like: **ApplicationRef.tick()** or **ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()** (see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/7787645)

**4. My confusions:**

- What I want is the state after a specific DOM element in a component get updated.
- **ngAfterViewChecked** will get fired by every async functions(by default), which is not suitable here I think.
- And **ApplicationRef.tick()** or **ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()** can force to trigger the change detection which will parse the whole component tree(from root to the child) which I think might be too costly.
- I'm wondering whether there is some function like:

```js
changeProperty(this.text => {
 this.text = 'A long long text';
 }).then( () => {
   // here is the state after the corresponding text is updated in the view
})
```

Or which is the right way to solve this problem here? 
Appreciate for any thoughts!

Comment: _`ngAfterViewChecked`... which is not suitable here I think_ - maybe consider it one more time. DOM is updated during change detection, and `ngAfterViewChecked` tells you when DOM finished updating. The solution by @smnbbrv although working in a browser, may not work on other platforms such as webworker, universal, nativescript etc.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, I also agree with your idea, since **ngAfterViewChecked** get fired every time after change detection finished. For this problem, I just want to get the latest state of one DOM component. **ngAfterViewChecked** is too "big". One possible solution I have found is to use **ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()** to force the change detection to update the view in my async callback function, which means to force this process happens earlier.

Comment: Right, I write in-depth about it in [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f). The side effect is that it runs change detection for all components. Just an idea, if you're interested in one particular property, maybe consider using a directive to render it's value and pass the value into directive through input.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, thanks for your idea, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that and I doubt it will ever appear.

However your particular problem can be solved in a totally different manner. As long as you want to control the way how your text / html gets rendered it is way easier to render it yourself.

Just set the innerHTML and the proper height will be in place

```
changeText(para) {
  para.innerHTML = 'long text';
  console.log(para.clientHeight);
}
```

and that's it. Remember that it may be better to use `innerText` or perform some HTML sanitizing before assigning it like that.